# Mongo Agregate: Set new field to true/false if an array has values or not

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here I'm trying to make a new field called `imADogOwner` and if `dogNames` has no values in the array set the field to false, if there are values in the array set it to true

```
{
    "imADogOwner": { $dogNames: true, $ne: [] }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the aggregation version of [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { imADogOwner: { $ne: [ "$dogNames", [] ] } }
    }
])
```